# Can we embed a countable compact subset of $\Bbb{Q}$ into the Cantor space? (Both use the standard topology.)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, cantor-set

Let X be a compact subspace of $\Bbb{Q}$ with cardinality countable, denote the Cantor space as $\mathcal{C}$. Is there a subspace $Y \subset \mathcal{C}$ and a mapping $f$ such that $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism?

A further question is, can we achieve the embedding into the rationals in the Cantor space? (That is, elements of the Y mentioned above are all rationals.)

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ itself already embedds into the Cantor space,no? If you want a closed copy of $X$ inside $\mathcal{C}$ this is a bit more interesting.

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan since $X$ is compact the copy of $X$ in $\mathcal C$ will always be closed for free

Comment: @JonathanSchilhan Now I get it that Q can embed into the Cantor space. But what about embedding into a rational subspace?

Comment: @Michael: what do you mean by "embedding into a rational subspace"? What is a rational subspace? Subspace of what?

Comment: It can easily be seen that every T2 regular, first countable, non-empty topological space without isolated points contains a copy of $\Bbb{Q}$, hence $\Bbb{Q}$, and every subspace of it, can be embedded into the Cantor set.

Comment: @Ulli By "embedding into a rational subspace", I mean to find a homeomorphism whose codomain consists of rationals in the Cantor set.

Comment: The rationals in the Cantor set are dense in it (see, for instance, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3595968/is-there-any-visual-proof-that-rationals-in-cantor-set-are-dense-in-cantor-set)), hence they contain no isolated points. Of course, they are countable. Therefore they are homeomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Ulli Thanks for your help!